# Setting Selected Value for DropDown List in ngFor Anular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

Below is My Angular5 Code

```
<div class="section">
        <h6 style="font-weight:bold">Select a Branch</h6>
        <select [(ngModel)]='Schedule.Branch'>
            <option *ngFor="let item of DataList;let i = index" value="{{item.Code}}" [selected]="i == 0">
              {{item.Name}}
            </option>
          </select>
      </div>
```

I saw a post on stackoverflow to set the selected option in Angular , same I tried in my code as

```
[selected]="i == 0 "
```

If I is equal to 0 means first option should be selected

i is defined in ngFor loop

```
*ngFor="let item of BranchList;let i = index"
```

but its not working, I also tried

```
[selected]="item.index == 0 "
```

But does not work , how can I set first option as selected ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to bind with `ngModel` if you are using `selected`, code your should be like this

```
<div class="section">
  <h6 style="font-weight:bold">Select a Branch</h6>
  <select >
      <option *ngFor="let item of this.dataList;let i = index" value="{{item.code}}" [selected]="i == 2">
        {{item.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dy2ocv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

`[(ngModel)]='schedule.branch'` and `[selected]="i == 0"` both are conflict. You use only one according to your faviour.

**HTML**

## Angular Dropdown

```
<div class="section">
    <h6 style="font-weight:bold">Select a Branch</h6>
    <select>
      <option *ngFor="let item of this.dataList;let i = index" value="{{item.code}}" [selected]="i == 0">
        {{item.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  dataList: Array<any> = [];
  schedule: { branch: '' };

  constructor() {
    this.dataList = [
      { code: 1, name: "shohel" },
      { code: 2, name: "rana" },
      { code: 3, name: "shipon" }
    ]
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dropdown-list)